# Xcode 4.5 iOS SDK 6.0 Beta 4 compiled app gives me thin white lines in background

Tags: ios6, xcode4.5

you all know the blue background with the thin white lines in the iOS "Settings" app. I set a grey background color for all of the views in my app which works as expected. Now when I build the exactly same code with the Xcode 4.5 (4G144l) "Preview"-Version with the iOS 6 beta 4 SDK an let it run on a device with iOS 6 beta 4 or the iPhone 6.0 Simulator my background grey is replaced by this "blue with thin white lines"-style and I have no clue why. No one seems to have this problem. Anyone?

thanx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem occurs for all tables that use the `UITableViewStyleGrouped` style and try to set a background color.  A change was made in iOS 6 that causes the background view to be set for these tables, which overrides the background color property.  The solution is to clear the background view in the UITableView.

`table.backgroundView = nil;`

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem, I'm using "[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:" to change the background images of all the tableviews in the app.

Fixed it by changing the background color of the TableView in the Storyboard from Default to Clear color.